# Windows Phone Emulator rendering issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7-emulator

I am starting with WP developing and i have Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone installed (on Windows 7 64bit). When I try to run emulator, it's bad rendered (see image below). Have you got any idea how to fix this issue? I can debug on my phone as well, but software emulator will be useful too. Thanks for any tip.

[image: Windows Phone Emulator]

Comment: Had the exact same problem with a bad video driver. In my case, I had to disable DirectX acceleration completely to make it work :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's got some problem with the emulator. Just set your grid background to black or any other color than transparent. This will solve the problem. I meant about the Layout grid background to black. If you make only content grid, then it will color only content area.

Comment: @PavelSterba you are welcome. Btw if you use windows phone 8 simulator you won't have any more such issues.